# Why do programs always compile to a.out? why not p.out or c.out or g.prog?

Tags: compiling, history

Historically speaking I know when I run the `cc` command or `gcc` my output generally always compiles to `a.out` unless I have a make file or use a particular flag on the compiler. But why `a.out`? Why not `c.out` or `c.run` or any myriad of a million possibilities?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1218262/why-do-some-compilers-use-a-out-as-the-default-name-for-executables

Comment: @John Yeah ithat definitely helps explain why `a.out` but even when we were compiling in assembler, I'm not sure that a.out made sense. `a.run` sure or `a.exe` (I know a windows/dos reference) because that seems to make more sense than `a.out`, it's not really output it's an executable application.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is a historical artefact, so in other words a legacy throwback. Historically `a.out` stands for ["assembler output"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A.out).

`a.out` is now only the name of the file but before it was also the file format of the executable.

The `a.out` executable format is nowadays uncommonly supported. The [ELF format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) has wider use, but we still keep the old name for the default output of the C compiler.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding upon @A.Meau's answer... in additional to being a historical artifact, [the default name of `a.out` is mandated by POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/c99.html):

> If there are no options that prevent link editing (such as **-c** or **-E**), and all input files compile and link without error, the resulting executable file shall be written according to the **-o** *outfile* option (if present) or to the file **a.out**.

This applies regardless of the actual binary format used for the executable. [`a.out` was originally associated with a specific format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A.out), but modern Linux systems generally use [ELF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format).